# How many answers does $x^5+y^3=z^2$ have in natural numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

how many answers does $x^5+y^3=z^2$ have in natural numbers?
I tried different ways but I couldn't succeed.

Comment: Sharing your progress would be nice

Comment: $(1,2,3)$ is a solution

Comment: Already solving the special case $x=5$ is not trivial

Comment: What a coincidence. I have started solving a problem from Canadian Mathematical Olympiad minutes ago which is *Prove that $x^2+y^5=z^3$ has infinitely many solutions in nonzero integers $x,y,z$*.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen why specifically $x = 5$ (just curious)?

Comment: You statement is equivalent as the one I quoted is $x^2=z^3-y^5$ and your is $z^2=y^3-(-x)^5$.

Comment: @TobErnack Oops, I wanted to say $x=1$ (and typed the exponent instead).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are infinitely many solutions.

It's a standard trick . . .

Just let $x,y,z$ be given by
$$x = 2^{3t},\;\;y=2^{5t},\;\;z=2^{\frac{15t+1}{2}}$$
where $t$ is any odd positive integer.